# UNIX Scripting Possibilities

Tags: macos, unix, bash-scripting, symantec

Need a small help to understand if a task can be accomplished using UNIX script.

**Situation:** Symantec Endpoint Encryption when installed on Mac, a manual intervention is required where a technician goes to user's machine and performs the 3 following steps:

1. Launch the Symantec Encryption Portal
2. Select the Drive that needs to be encrypted
3. Enter username & password and click OK.

Is it possible that these 3 steps can be done by script?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a path to investigate,

1. [PGP Command Line](http://www.symantec.com/command-line?fid=encryption)
2. [HOW TO: Install PGP Command Line on Mac OS X](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=HOWTO42038)

Ref: Symantec [Encryption Family](http://www.symantec.com/products-solutions/families/?fid=encryption) page.